# What should I add to this C code to open more than 1 file?

Tags: c

This code searches for a set of numbers in a file; if it finds it, it displays the line where it found it. I want this code to search into more than 1 file. After it finished searching in the 1st file, it'll start searching in the second one and so on.

This is the output:

[image: Output of the code showing where it found the number in question]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

    int busca(char *str, char *archNom);
    void archivo(char *nomArchivo);


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   int result, errno;

   if(argc < 3 || argc > 3)
   {
      archivo(argv[0]);
      exit(1);
   }

   result = busca(argv[1], argv[2]);
```

Comment: Hi, that code searches for a number in a file, I want the code to search in another file after it finished searching in the first file and so on.

Comment: Note that you probably will revise the command line format to put the number/string you are searching for as the first argument, and then have the list of file names as the second and subsequent arguments, and you'll process standard input if no file name is given.  That's the standard way of organizing a command line on Unix.  You collect the match, then loop of the remaining arguments, treating each as a file name.  You might revise the code to separate file opening and closing from processing so that you can simply pass `stdin` to the processing function.

Comment: Also note that the `errno` you define in your code is not the `errno` that will be set by failing functions.  You need to use `#include <errno.h>` to get access to the orthodox global variable `errno`.  And no, it is not OK to write `extern int errno;` because that is not always a correct declaration for it (e.g. in a threaded environment, it is usually more like: `extern int *_Errno(void); #define errno (*_Errno())` so that the function can return the thread-local storage for `errno`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestions @JonathanLeffler, it deffinetly looks better using the string and the files after the string and now it works correctly :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could iterate over `argv`, from `1` to `argc - 2` (excluding the first and last elements), and then just run `busca(argv[n], argv[argc - 1])` once for each item in the `argv` array. You'd have to keep track of the result to determine wether an error occurred, perhaps using `min()` or `max()`.

Comment: Thank you very much, you gave me a good idea, I changed my code a little bit in order to follow what I needed.